# How to plot a histogram given a set of frequencies for data values?

Tags: plotting

I have generated many random variables within a specific function, and have counted them up. So far, I have counted the variables:

```
 bcount1=BinCounts[function,{0,20,1}]
 {86,10,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Now I need to generate a histogram with a bin width of 1 that'll display something like:

x-axis 0 to 1 ---> a bar 86 units high
x-axis 1 to 2 ---> a bar 10 units high
x-axis 2 to 3 -->  a bar 2 units high

and so on and so forth....however the Histogram function is giving me the reverse. It's telling me something from 80 to 100 is a bar 1 unit high..

Can I get some help with appropriate syntax?

Comment: Similar to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70059/how-to-create-a-histogram-from-a-given-frequency-table

Comment: For a true histogram you would be better off having a bar 86 units high from -.5 to .5, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
bincounts = {86, 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
bins = Range[0, 20, 1];
```

You can use `BarChart`:

```
BarChart[bincounts]
```

Or `Histogram` after reconstructing an input data set using `bins` and `bincounts`:

```
Histogram[Flatten[ConstantArray[##] & @@@ Transpose[{Most@bins, bincounts}]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {86, 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
BarChart[data, ChartLabels -> Range[20]]
```

[image]

If you must have a true histogram:

```
Histogram[Flatten[Table[i, {i, Length[data]}, {j, data[[i]]}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but I still have a counter for "86" through a bar that is 1 unit in height. I want a bar 86 units in height to represent the number of data sets between 0 and 1 that were generated from my function. I had a previous function that generated random variables for many simulations, and I'm counting how many of those simulated variables fall within a range. I just need a histogram that has 0 to 1 with a height of 86, 1 to 2 with a height of 10, 2 to 3 with a height of 2, 3 to 4 with a height of 0, etc. etc

Comment: David, care to edit your post ?

Answer (score 1):

```
values = Range[0, 20];
frequencies = {86, 10, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
n = Length[values]; (* 21 *)
data = Flatten@Array[Table[values[[#]], {frequencies[[#]]}] &, n];

Histogram[data, {First@values, Last@values, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]