# Histogram plot for fixed class interval

Tags: histograms

```
Age     Size of Kidney
0-20     8.5
20-40    9.2
40-60    10.4
60-80    9.3
80-100   8.9
```

The above data gives the average size of the kidney for the people of age groups given in the fixed interval of age groups. How to plot the above data using Mathematica in Histogram?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a Histrogram, because you are not providing the underlying data. Do you just want a `BarChart` with five different bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't sound like an application for Histogram, because you are not providing the underlying data.

It sounds like you are looking for a labeled bar chart. You can achieve this using `BarChart` and the `ChartLabels` options. For example:

```
BarChart[{8.5, 9.2, 10.4, 9.3, 8.9}, ChartLabels -> {"0-20", "20-40", "40-60", "60-80", "80-100"}, AxesLabel -> {"Age Range", "Average Height"}]
```

You can also use associations where the keys are labels associated with the values. I find this easier to enter and read. For example,

```
BarChart[<|"0-20" -> 8.5, "20-40" -> 9.2, "40-60" -> 10.4, "60-80" -> 9.3, "80-100" -> 8.9|>, ChartLabels -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"Age Range", "Average Height"}]
```

In either case, you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One query, How can I add different colors for different bars and join the mid points of the top of every bars to form a curve. Thanks...

Comment: @RoshanShrestha, use the `ChartStyle` and `Joined` options of `BarChart`; e.g., add `ChartStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow, Cyan}, Joined->Automatic` in `BarChart[...]`.

Comment: Thanks, Also, by default, there is spacing between bars, Can we remove spaces between bars, so that they are joined ?

Comment: I used BarSpacing->None, but the first bar is still not joined with the y-axis.

Comment: @RoshanShrestha, try `AxesOrigin -> {.5, 0}`.

Comment: Thanks alot. I used Joined option like you said, but is there any way so that even values like 8.5,9.2,10.4.9.3 and 8.9 are seen at the bars where the lines are joined. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`BarChart` is the right approach to view this kind of data. If you have to use `Histogram` for some reason, here is how you can use it

```
heights = {8.5, 9.2, 10.4, 9.3, 8.9};
labels = {"0-20", "20-40", "40-60", "60-80", "80-100"};

hist = Histogram[{1}, {Range[0, 100, 20]}, (heights &), 
  ChartStyle -> 1, Ticks -> {Thread[{Range[10, 100, 20], labels}], Automatic}, 
  Epilog -> ListLinePlot[heights, DataRange -> {10, 90}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}][[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]